# How do I emulate MATLAB's comet plot?

Tags: plotting, animation

I have tried the following code:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[12 u] Cos[u], Sin[12 u] Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and it produced the following image:

[image: Flower]

MATLAB has a [`comet`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/comet.html) command that will draw this parametric plot in real time, allowing the viewer to watch as the particle traces out the plot. Is there a way to do this in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Animate.html), you'll note that I added some options, remove them to see why :)

```
Animate[
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[12 u] Cos[u], Sin[12 u] Sin[u]}, {u, 0, umax},
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
 {umax, 0.1, 2 Pi}]
```

You can change `Animate` to [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) if you wish to slide back and forth manually as well

Comment: `Animate` seems like `Manipulate` in many ways, it allows manual control of the slider as well, it merely starts it running automatically.

Answer (score 16):

```
frames = Table[
  ParametricPlot[{Sin[12 u] Cos[u], Sin[12 u] Sin[u]}, {u, 0, t}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, .001, 2 Pi, 2.1 Pi/100}]
```

and then either

```
ListAnimate[frames]
```

or

```
Export["movie.gif", frames]
```

depending on what you want. The latter yields

[image]

You can also do this:

```
 Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Sin[12 u] Cos[u], Sin[12 u] Sin[u]}, {u, 0, t}, 
       PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, .01, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: I just went back and applied this to some of my diff. eq. homework and this is amazing. Thank you!

Comment: @Reid: Glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

Unchecked :

```
 Needs["NETLink`"]
 m = CreateCOMObject["matlab.application"]

 m@Execute["t = 0:.01:2*pi;
            x = sin(12*t).*(cos(t));
            y = sin(12*t).*(sin(t));
            comet(x,y);"]
```

First seen this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870788/656841).

Answer (score 2):

The more MATLAB-like solution:

```
Animate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{Sin[4 x] Cos[x], Sin[4 x] Sin[x]}, {x, 0, y},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
  ParametricPlot[{Sin[4 z] Cos[z], Sin[4 z] Sin[z]}, 
   {z, y - 0.02 \[Pi], y}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]], 
  Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8],
   Point[{Sin[4 y] Cos[y], Sin[4 y] Sin[y]}]}]],
 {y, 0, 2 \[Pi],0.001 \[Pi]}
]
```

Here's the gif output:

[image]

Personally I prefer that the full orbital be kept as background with comet moving on it. In that case I change the parameter maximum to 2[Pi] instead of y, in the first ParametricPlot. (I use angular frequency 4 instead of 12 to make the animation smoother. If you raise the angular frequency, you should use more points, that is, smaller step, in animation so that it is smooth enough. Otherwise it looks silly to use comet plot.)